# mySQL init file is not executing

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to initialise my mysql database in docker compose however its not working for some reason and i cant figure out what im doing wrong.

This is my folder structure:

```
- testdb
  - init db
      - init.sql
- docker-compose.yaml
```

My docker compose file looks like this where all of the commented out lines are ones i have tried:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro

    #  this one showed the database in the container but it was not added
    #  as the database did not show up in the database


    # tried and failed
    # - mysql_data_drive:/var/lib/mysql
    # - /Users/name/mything/anotherfolder/testdb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    # - ./testdb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    # - ./testdb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    # - ./test-sql-2:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    # - ./init/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    # - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    # - ./init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    # - ./init/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    # - ./init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    # - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    # - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    # - ./testdb/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
# volumes:
#   mysql_data_drive:
#     driver: local
```

Can anyone see whats going on here?

Comment: you have a space in `init db` folder name ? remove that db from the name and use a volume `./testdb/init/mysqldatabase.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ysqldatabase.sql:`

Comment: Where are you seeing any space?

Comment: in your folder structure section

Comment: Theres no spaces, I have also tried your version and it doesnt work either. Thanks anyway though